# Convert crystal report to pdf in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, crystal-reports

How to convert **Crystal Report** to **PDF** file in **VB.Net**,

I am using Crystal Report Version **10.0.0533**

My code is

```
Private Sub ExpData()
    If RepRs.BOF Or RepRs.EOF Then
        MsgBox("No Details Found", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        RepRs.Close()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    RepRs.MoveFirst()

    Dim RepDoc As New ReportDocument
    Dim rptLoc As String = ""
    rptLoc = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Reports\SalesBillACInvoice.rpt"
    RepDoc.Load(rptLoc)
    RepDoc.SetDataSource(RepRs)

    Reports.CRViewer.ReportSource = RepDoc

    Reports.Show()  'I want to export here instead of showing...
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do like this,

Created new folder to save PDF files in application startup path, folder name is PDF.

Remove this line

```
Reports.Show()
```

Add this code

```
Try
    Dim CrExportOptions As ExportOptions
    Dim CrDiskFileDestinationOptions As New DiskFileDestinationOptions()
    Dim CrFormatTypeOptions As New PdfRtfWordFormatOptions()
    Dim FilePath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\PDF\" & "SalesBillACInvoice.pdf"
    CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = FilePath
    CrExportOptions = RepDoc.ExportOptions
    With CrExportOptions
        .ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
        .ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
        .DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions
        .FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions
    End With
    RepDoc.Export()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the technique I use. No server side folder required.

```
        RepDoc.SetDataSource(RepRs) 'Add dataset to report
        RepDoc.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, HttpContext.Current.Response, True, "AttachmentName")
        RepDoc.Close()
        RepDoc.Dispose()
```

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/ExportCRtoPDF10062006161918PM/ExportCRtoPDF.aspx